# P2P hand-shaking without a central server

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-programming, p2p

I wrote a client-server application designed to exchange files (among other things) over the local area network. In server mode, the application listens for TCP connections with a specific identification header. In client mode, it tries to establish TCP connections to IP Addresses that are provided by the user.

I now need to adapt this application to work over the internet. Without much exposure to network programming, I am not sure how to achieve this without some kind of a central server (for announcing presence, etc.). This is not an option.

Suppose I have the app running in server mode on my machine which is behind a home network. You (the reader) have the app in client mode and we need to connect. Neither of us have static IP addresses. Is there a way for the client to reach the server? Both the server and client could figure out their public IP addresses but beyond that, I'm not sure what to do.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Based on the answers, some clarification is in order. My question is not about discovery. Both client and server can query their public addresses and users can exchange these IPs over some other medium. The question is, how to establish a connection once each other's IPs are known but both parties are behind networks which do not have the appropriate port forwardings. My app uses port 51200 as a default over TCP for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few months ago I was looking for a similar solution, but unfortunately I got stuck and henceforth I dropped it.

People say you could use [UDP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) or [TCP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching), but I was unable to do this (I'm not a specialist in computer networks though). Whether it will work or not depends on the network itself.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519818/how-to-create-a-p2p-connection-when-both-clients-are-behind-nat) is the question I originally asked, maybe it will be helpful to you. Honestly, I don't want to kill your hopes, but I'm afraid it may be a dead end. :(

Answer (score 5):

I've learned that the techniques of UDP hole punching to obtain a true direct connection between 2 peers, is imperfect due to some possible combinations of NAT types involved. What this means is that UDP hole punching **alone** is not always going to work.

The way to claim 100% operability is to, in the cases where a p2p connection is impossible, use a relay server. The process of discovering whether a true p2p connection is possible has been standardized by ICE,TURN,and STUN. All I know is that using ICE/TURN/STUN seems to be the standardized strategy in subverting the NAT problem. It can facilitate a true p2p connection when available and offer relaying services when necessary.

**Note**: I use the term p2p in this answer to distinguish a truly direct connection between 2 endpoints, not to be confused with overlay networks and the like.

**Advanced Users**: It is possible to gain more direct p2p connections by introducing more complicated strategies to cooperate with symmetric NAT behaviour, such as port prediction, etc. But the libraries that implement these methods are costly, and seems too difficult for a DIY job.

I have not explained in detail the different types of NAT connection possibilities. You will want to research on NAT types and how they relate to UDP hole punching. There are RFCs out there and I will try to update my answer with links. But the point is that you can avert a lot of this learning by refocusing on implementing TURN/STUN/ICE, learn how they are implemented and how you can use their standardized behavior.

## Potential Solutions

- [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/) - contains a stand-alone high level NAT traversal library for C/C++, also has bindings for other langauges. If you just want the NAT Traversal library sub-component, see [PJNATH](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/latest/pjnath/docs/html/index.htm)
- [LibJingle](https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/index?hl=pl) - a P2P (peer-to-peer) and RTC (real-time communication) stack that builds on XMPP. Note that many of LibJingle implementation is not interoperable with actual XMPP Jingle specification and subsidiary specifications.

These may add considerable complexity to the program, which is why it can be compelling to implement some of the mechanisms myself.

## Documents

- [NAT on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)
- [NAT Traversal Fundamentals](http://www.holest.com/index.php/sp2p-nat-traversal-and-peer-to-peer-system/80-peer-to-peer-systems.html)
- [How NAT Compatible are VoIP Applications](http://www.di.unipi.it/%7Ericci/NAT-compatible.pdf)
- [STUN server list](https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933)
- [Teredo/Shipworm Doc](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-ngtrans-shipworm-07#section-3)
- [Symmetric NAT and UDP Hole Punching](https://serverfault.com/questions/529961/symmetric-nat-and-udp-hole-punching)
- [STUN/TURN/ICE Summary](http://www.eyeball.com/standards/stun-turn-ice/)

### IETF

**RFCs**

- [RFC 5245 – ICE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5245/)
- [RFC 5389 – STUN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389)
- [RFC 5766 – TURN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766) (iirc, TURN uses a STUN server.)
- [RFC 5768 – ICE – SIP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5768)
- [RFC 6336 – ICE – IANA Registry](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6336.txt)
- [RFC 6544 – ICE – TCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6544)
- [RFC 5928 – TURN Resolution Mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5928)
- [RFC 6062 – TURN Extensions for TCP Allocations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6062)
- [RFC 6156 – TURN Extension for IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6156)
- [[Draft] Symmetric NAT Traversal using STUN](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-takeda-symmetric-nat-traversal-00)
- [[Draft] Network Address Translation and Peer-to-Peer Applications (NATP2P)](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/%7Ebaford/nat/draft-ford-natp2p-00.txt)

### Microsoft

- [MS-STUN – Microsoft STUN extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd906831(v=office.12).aspx)
- [MS-TURN – Microsoft TURN extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc431507(v=office.12).aspx)
- [MS-ICE – Microsoft ICE extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc431495(v=office.12).aspx)
- [MS-ICE2 – Microsoft ICE2 extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc431504(v=office.12).aspx)

## Notes

I have heard that the eventual migration to IPv6 may squash the NAT traversal problem, but [[probably not]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647633/nat-traversal-and-ipv6). Someone could enlighten this topic. Either way, the progression to IPv6 appears slow from my non-experienced viewpoint, and I wouldn't count on it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible without some sort of central place to "find" each other. You need some way for the client the find the servers ip address to connect to.

Also, udp or tcp hole punching is an entirely different thing and uses, guess what: a central server.

Comment: Thanks. Both parties can query their public IP addresses and can also exchange each other's IP's. So the issue is not about discovery. It is more about how to reach each other behind their home network which would not have appropriate port forwardings.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IPv6 it is possible - but you still need to know the other parties address. It also is possible if you use a DynDns service - but that is already a kind of central infrastructure.